# Android list view with header

Tags: android-listview

I noticed that when adding a header view to a list view ,index for items start with 1,but if the list view doesn't have a header then index for items starts with 0.What is the design principle for this?

Comment: Because **this way** to add a header really inserts another item (with index = 0). And the header itself vanishes on scroll. I simply use another View **above** the ListView and that's my **fixed** header. Same for the footer.

Comment: Having separate view for list view header is easy to use,but it may be needed in some situations to add header to list view and it has its own advantage also,otherwise it wouldn't have been added.What is worrying me is the index change.

Comment: With my method, the index is always 0. Because there is no "fake header" taking it for itself.